# Mesh is partially transparent in Material preview

Tags: mesh, materials, uv, 3d-view, transparency

Mesh looks like this in Material Preview:
[image]

Normal view
[image: Normal view]

I've recalculated normals but it does nothing.
Does anyone know what is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The mesh was imported from Maya and it gets imported with the alpha blend in Evee settings.
Found the answer on this thread: https://blenderartists.org/t/models-are-partially-see-through/1178366/2